# Templated class as argument in another templated class method

Tags: c++, templates

Let's consider following example. I have two classes: *Point* and *Cuboid*

**point.h**

```
template<typename T>
class Point
{
public:
    Point(T x, T y, T z);
    ~Point();
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;

};
```

**cuboid.h**

```
template<typename T>
class Cuboid
{
public:
    Cuboid(Point<T> start, T width, T height, T length);
    ~Cuboid();
    Point<T> start;
    T width;
    T height;
    T length;
};
```

However, compiler doesn't like the line:

```
Cuboid(Point<T> start, T width, T height, T length);
```

The compilation error is:

> > error: expected ')' before '<' token

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: did you forget to include point.h in cuboid.h? this compiles and runs fine http://ideone.com/zALlWp

Comment: Umm, I had a little mess in the code. I had to put .cpp and .h inside one .h file and then include it in cuboid.h. Problem solved, thank you!